# Using CentOS virtual box guest OS as a local web server

Tags: centos, webserver, virtualbox

I've installed CentOS as a virtual box os under my osx host, and have been trying to use it as a local web server, but I've run into some problems.

First, I want to establish that I've installed apache, mysql, and php properly using yum. 
Now, those of you familiar with virtual os's, how do I access my centos virtual os through my osx host. It does not show automatically in my osx network. I tried ifconfig in centos, but I got a weird ip 10.0.2.1 or something, and that does not work.

I just want to know what I should do next to setup my virtual os as a network drive.

Thanks.

Comment: What virtualization software are you using? You need to configure it for bridged networking (sounds like it's configured for NAT right now).

Comment: I'm using VirtualBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to get the virtual server on your LAN. If you shut down the VM and go to the settings, you can set the network to bridged. When it boots up again you should see the IP address similar to your Mac. I would expect something like `192.168.x.y`.

Once that is done, check you can ping the VM from your Mac on the CentOS IP.

Now to test apache works, open `http://centos IP`

To test PHP is working with apache you will need to create a file in the document root of you web server on CentOS. This will be /var/www unless you have changed it. Create a file index.php and put the following inside

```
<?php

echo "I am PHP";
```

Now visit `http://centos IP/index.php` and you should see "`I am PHP`".

To test that mysql support is available for php, edit the PHP file again and add

```
mysql_connect( 'root', '', 'localhost' );
```

Open `http://centos IP/index.php` again, and if you get an error saying cannot connect, then mysql support is working, if you get an error about function mysql_connect doesn't exist you need to install php-mysql using Yum.

You can use samba or nfs to share a folder on your CentOS machine to make it available as a network share.

Answer (score 2):

You can use NAT type and make Port Forwarding. e.g. your host is 172.1.1.1 and virtual machine has 10.0.2.1, go to Preferences → select Network tab and click Advanced, then click Port Forwarding. Add new rule where host ip is 172.1.1.1, host port 5050 (or any available), guest ip 10.0.2.1 and guest port 80. 
Create file "phpinfo.php" in /var/www with

```
<?php

// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();

?>
```

Now you can open browser on your host machine and open http://172.1.1.1:5050